Google Translate, Gender Voice Parameter
I am trying to extract sound from Google Translate. Using this Javascript answer here , how do I parameterize to use a man or woman voice in the sound recording? I could not find the API Specs.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/79194696/15435022

I'm not familiar with the Python SDK for Google Translate, but I see that Google TTS has the specific texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender to use:
Example:
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code="en-US",
        name=voice_name,   
        ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE
    )

With four possible values: SSML_VOICE_GENDER_UNSPECIFIED, MALE, FEMALE, NEUTRAL
For now, it seems the only possible option

can you put a link to the docs? thank you !

Sorry, I didn't realize an additional step was required, sending translated text to TTS API. My example works with text to speech, just tried it. There's no code in your question, it misled me
